# Why does file encryption using mcrypt fail?

Tags: php, encryption, aes, mcrypt

I have an issue using mcrypt to encrypt a file on filesystem to e.g. store it into Mysql database. I have reduced the issue to the following lines of code:

```
<?php
$key = vzc_generateKey();

$file_content = file_get_contents("test.pdf"); // Fails
$file_content = file_get_contents("test2.docx"); // Fails
//$file_content = "12323"; // Works great

$hash_start = md5($file_content);

$encrypt = vzc_encryptV3($file_content, $key);

$decrypt = vzc_decryptV3($encrypt, $key);

$hash_end = md5($decrypt);

echo ($hash_end == $hash_start)."##";

function vzc_generateKey()
{
    $cstrong = false;

    while ($cstrong == false)
    {
        $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16, $cstrong);
    }

    return bin2hex($bytes);
}

function vzc_decryptV3($crypt,$key) {

    $content = base64_decode($crypt['crypt']);
    $iv = $crypt['iv'];

    $rijndael = 'rijndael-256';

    $cp = mcrypt_module_open($rijndael, '', 'ofb', '');

    $ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($cp);

    $key = substr(md5($key), 0, $ks);

    mcrypt_generic_init($cp, $key, $iv);

    $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($cp, $content);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cp);

    mcrypt_module_close($cp);

    return trim(base64_decode($decrypted));

}

function vzc_encryptV3($file_content,$key) {

    $content = base64_encode($file_content);

    $rijndael = 'rijndael-256';

    $cp = mcrypt_module_open($rijndael, '', 'ofb', '');

    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN')
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($cp), MCRYPT_RAND);
    else
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($cp), MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

    $ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($cp);

    $key = substr(md5($key), 0, $ks);

    mcrypt_generic_init($cp, $key, $iv);

    $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($cp, $content);

    $returnvalue = array("crypt"=>trim(base64_encode($encrypted)), "iv"=>$iv);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cp);

    mcrypt_module_close($cp);

    return $returnvalue;

}

?>
```

Using the String "12323" everything works fine, both Hashes do equal. But those two test files (one pdf and one docx) fail. It seems that the decryption returns different values then the origin data.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thank you very much in advance for any tip you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the fact that the files are not exactly n * blocksize long. This leads the algorithm to pad the end of the file with '\0' and this changes the content of the file when you do the md5 calculation.

One way around this is to strip the padding off of the last block, if you can reliably find the end of the file.